# Make the input enabled after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" id="examination"  class="form-control" name="exam" placeholder="Enter Title">
<label>Enable Exam</label>
</div>
```

And this is my disabled input:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Order</label>
<input  id="myorder" name="myorder" disabled>
</div>
```

I try with this script to make the input enabled after checkbox checked, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#examination').change(function(){
   $("#myorder").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you sure have a lot of questions with answers given; none accepted.

Comment: Also, your code it works perfectly. What's the problem ? Maybe you forgot to include jquery plugin.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Nothing happened after clicking checkbox

Comment: @YazanMehrez, here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9uggjmy/

Answer (score 0):

Here, i think this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chtest').change(function(e){
        var isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
        if (isChecked) {
            $("#test").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#test").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="test" disabled="disabled"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chtest">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```